# GASで変数の中身にシングルクォーテーションを付けたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**変数の中身にシングルクォーテーションを付けたい**
次のようなスプレットシートから取得してきた値にシングルクォーテーションを付けたいです。
例えばセルの中の値が abcde だった場合 'abcde'と出力したいです。
どのようにすればよいでしょうか？
基礎的な内容ですがよくわからないのでよろしくお願いします。

```
function get_value() {
  var x = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx',0);

  var acoord = x.getRange(2,3);
  var a = acoord.getValue();
　console.log(a);
};
```

**試してみたこと**
こういうように値を直接 \　でした。
しかし、中身はいじらずにやりたいと考えている。

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = "\'abcde\'";
  console.log(x);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

普通に`"'"+acoord.getValue()+"'"`とすればいいのでは？